# If non-static method can be static without any bad impact on code?

Tags: php, oop

I'm new to OOP. I saw an example at below. the `getStudentName()` has been set as a static method. Based on the OOP knowledge I have, this method should be a non-static method.

However, the code is still work even though it is wrong. I would like to know if non-static method can be static  without any bad impact on code?

BTW, the code is writing by PHP.

```
class student{

    public static function getStudentName($studentID){
             ....
             return $studentName;

    }

}

$stuName = student::getStudentName($stuID)
```

Comment: What does the getStudentName() method do? The difference between static and non-static methods is if they operate on instance variables or not. Static methods cannot operate directly on instance variables since there is no instance available.

Comment: Why do you think the method should be non-static?

Comment: @deceze, because each student has its name, getStudentName() should be for each $studentObj, not the method for the class.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you can call a static method as a normal one in PHP.

`$someStudent->getStudentName()`

`student::getStudentName()`

But you wouldn't have a $this.

If it's a good idea to make this concrete method static depends on it's functionallity.

If it should get you the name of a student-object, make it normal.

If it should search all the studentobjects for an ID and retrieve the name of that object, make it static.

Answer (score 0):

Depends.

Your class 'student' must be a student. studentId is an attribute and it is stored in the database. retrive que student, or the student name, from a database is a different thing.

If you use the ActiveRecord pattern, ok, the own class know such thing but is much more relevant do this

```
$instance = student::find($id);
$name = $instance->name();
```

but in some cases you can do only this

```
$name = student::find_and_return_the_name($id);
```

if the resource is much expensive to build.

Answer (score 0):

PHP allows you to ignore or infer the "static" keyword, and only throw an E_STRICT error (hidden under the default error_reporting mask).